# Java Regex Matching Until Character

Tags: java, regex

Here's my (ugly) regex in java:

```
\\[(\\d{2}?)/(\\d{2}?)/(\\d{2}?) (\\d{2}?):(\\d{2}?) - \\w+?\\] (.+?)(?=\\[)
```

It ideally parses into 6 groups MM, DD, YY, etc..:

```
 [MM/DD/YY HH:mm - userName] commentUntilNextBracket
```

This works in my java program except for `(?=\\[)`, the last part of the regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_STRING);
Matcher m = p.matcher(comment));
while(m.find()){ //do something}
```

Removing the look ahead would allow me to get 'c' in "commentUntilNextBracket" but I want the whole string. I tested this using: [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

It actually worked with the entire regex expression. Here is an example input I tried in both my program and Regex Planet. It worked on the latter. It found all 4 matches and 0-6 groups.

> [04/24/15 11:16 - username] office [04/25/15 13:25 - username] what [04/27/15 07:45 - username] officeNote [04/27/15 08:59 - username] check [04/27/15 09:01 - username] double check

So what am I doing wrong where my Java8 is not find any matches? It only find matches when I remove the look around. Thanks. (Side note, if you can 'beautify' the regex, that'd be cool too ;] )

Comment: Works fine for me, except the `double check` group that requires `(?=\\[|$)`. Note that you need `Pattern.DOTALL` flag if your input is multiline.

Comment: @axtavt Wow. Um, that actually fixed my original expression....woah, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\[\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+ - \w+\]
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/90k6r6)

Then the comments:

```
\[(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+) - \w+\]([^\[]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ4wE6/1)

Or in [Regex Planet](http://fiddle.re/qzxea6)

---

You asked for an explanation of `[^\[]*`:

1. The outer `[   ]` are to declare a character class such as `[0123456789]` for a single character;
2. The `^` inside the character class negates it, ie any single character except a member of the class;
3. `\[` need to escape the opening bracket, so a literal `[`
4. `*` is a quantifier applied to the previous pattern -- in this case the negated character class.

So this `[^\[]*` means zero or more characters except a `[`

Comment: This looks nice and clean! Thanks! It'd be awesome if you can explain ([^\[]*) I tried following that but got lost

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex that uses lazy matching and a look-ahead that includes the `[` and end-of-string/line `$` test:

```
\\[(\\d{2}?)/(\\d{2}?)/(\\d{2}?)\\s+(\\d{2}?):(\\d{2}?)\\s+-\\s+\\w+?\\]\\s+(.+?)(?=\\s*\\[|$)
```

This will match all the cases you have.

[Demo](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiayv8SDA/index.html) on RegexPlanet, or just a showcase on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uC4fX3/1) to see what the regex does.

I'd also recommend to use `\s` instead of literal spaces, as it will match any whitespace and will be easier to maintain (especially, when testing with the verbose option ON). To match hard spaces, you can replace `\s` with `\p{Zs}`. Actually, we can make it fully Unicode-"compatible":

```
REGEX: \[(\p{N}{2}?)/(\p{N}{2}?)/(\p{N}{2}?)\p{Zs}+(\p{N}{2}?):(\p{N}{2}?)\p{Zs}+-\p{Zs}+[\p{L}\p{N}_]+?\]\p{Zs}+(.+?)(?=\p{Zs}*\[|$)

JAVA: String ptrn = "\\[(\\p{N}{2}?)/(\\p{N}{2}?)/(\\p{N}{2}?)\\p{Zs}+(\\p{N}{2}?):(\\p{N}{2}?)\\p{Zs}+-\\p{Zs}+[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]+?\\]\\p{Zs}+(.+?)(?=\\p{Zs}*\\[|$)";
```

Comment: this worked too! May I ask why \s is used over literal space? To me, it just seems confusing already and the literal space seems obvious? Thanks!

Comment: @AnotherNewbplusplus: The regex is quite straightforward, the `\s` pattern is just safer since in some cases (like when you test a regex, when you use verbose option on), the spaces in the pattern are not accounted for. Also, in case there is a hard space, you could use `\p{Zs}` Unicode class to match all kind of spaces.